# AngularJS Fancybox Popup

Tags: angularjs, fancybox

I have started an angularjs project and I would like to implement fancybox.

For this, I have included the jQuery and fancybox plugins to the solution. I am attempting to open the template in the code shown below in a fancybox window.

**View**

`<a href="" ng-click="openPage('popups/add.html')">ADD</a>`

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController',
    function MainController($scope) {
        $scope.user = "Hey Welcome";

        $scope.open = function(template_path){
            $.fancybox({"href":template_path})
        }
    }
)
```

And **popup/add.html**

```
<div class="pop-contnr">
    <h2>ADD</h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align=center>{{user}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Fancybox successfully opens a window containing the template, but the `{{user}}` expression has not been evaluated. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have created a directive for fancybox

```
app.directive('fancybox',function($compile, $timeout){
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.fancybox({
                hideOnOverlayClick:false,
                hideOnContentClick:false,
                enableEscapeButton:false,
                showNavArrows:false,
                onComplete: function(){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        $compile($("#fancybox-content"))($scope);
                        $scope.$apply();
                        $.fancybox.resize();
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it will be useful if you also included the html sample as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simplified version of a fancybox directive my team and I wrote to open fancyboxes based on a template with a single click.

It is invoked in the markup like this:

```
<div fancybox ng-click="openFancybox('templateUrl')"> </div>
```

The code for the directive is:

```
app.directive('fancybox', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        controller: function($scope) {
             $scope.openFancybox = function (url) {

                $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    if (response.status == 200) {

                        var template = angular.element(response.data);
                        var compiledTemplate = $compile(template);
                        compiledTemplate($scope);

                        $.fancybox.open({ content: template, type: 'html' });
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

It can be seen working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENi6BkdVFKe5c02uUciv?p=preview)

Comment: I don't want to load the template each time the element is clicked - is there any posibility to load that template only once ?

Comment: Great stuff, much appreciated! Looks like Angular's internal template loader (in the directive) was having issues getting recognised by fancybox on initialization... this method guarantees the template is really there for it.

Comment: @Tony - the browser will be caching the template, so will save HTTP round trip.

Comment: Can I do this without using jquery?

Comment: @pandudas - Fancybox is based on jQuery, so it won't work without it. Here are the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). You'd have to use a different framework for your modals that is not jquery based.

Answer (score 1):

I extended the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23870166/4127142) to use Angular's template cache.

It is invoked in the markup like this:

```
<div fancybox fancybox-template="template.html">Open Fancybox</div>
```

The code for the directive is:

```
app.directive('fancybox', function ($templateRequest, $compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.openFancybox = function (url) {
                $templateRequest(url).then(function(html){
                    var template = $compile(html)($scope);
                    $.fancybox.open({ content: template, type: 'html' }); 
                });
            };
        },
        link: function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                var url = attrs.fancyboxTemplate;
                scope.openFancybox(url);
            });
        },
    }
});
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFMj2aFS6eNGJ8Nk5jCx?p=preview).