# converting Fancybox plugin to Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive, fancybox

I'm using `ng-repeat` place a *url* to an *iframe* {{item.details}} in each button, which is working correctly.
HTML:

```
<a class="various small_button shadow none" fancybox ng-href="{{item.details}}">View Details</a>
```

The problem is creating a directive for `fancybox` to create a `lightbox iframe` when the button is clicked. I've attempted to resolve this by viewing these posts  [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127725/trying-to-convert-jquery-plugin-to-angular-directive) and [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057130/angularjs-fancybox-popup) and a few others, they were helpful but were not a solution in this case.

**Fancybox directive:**

```
app.directive('fancybox', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'e',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            element.fancybox({  
                type        :'iframe',
                scrolling   : 'no',
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 400,
                fitToView   : true,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : true,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                source      :function(current){
                    return $(current.element);

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

With jQuery I was invoking `fancybox` with classes ".various" and ".ad". I want invoke `fancybox` the same way only using angular.

Original Fancy jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//fancybox window script
    $(".various").fancybox({
        type        :'iframe',
        scrolling   : 'no',
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 400,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : true,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
    });

    $(".ad").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 210,
        maxHeight   : 140,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '100%',
        height      : '100%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : true,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });


});//set up close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
app.directive('fancybox', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      $(element).fancybox({  
        type        :'iframe',
        scrolling   : 'no',
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 400,
        fitToView   : true,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : true,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The attribute `restrict` must be `A` (uppercase) since in your example the directive is an attribute. `E` (uppercase) is when the directive is an element. You can use combined: `restrict: 'AE'`. [More information](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

You need use `$(element).fancybox({ ... })` because fancybox is a jquery plugin.

Comment: Thank You @carlos Forero

Comment: Thank you @CarlosForero. but if the same route is visited multiple times, the directive ends up creating multiple event handlers each time. How can I handle that?